# Googlebot crawl errors / robots.txt permissions on a VPS server

Tags: search-engine, bots, robots.txt, googlebot

I've been getting these strange errors, but only recently, on a domain. I'm on a VPS with HostGator, and I just don't see anything wrong.

```
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google
Disallow:
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-includes/
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /.qidb/
Sitemap: http://www.occupyhln.org/sitemap.xml
Sitemap: http://www.occupyhln.org/sitemap_index.xml
Sitemap: http://www.occupyhln.org/post-sitemap.xml
Sitemap: http://www.occupyhln.org/page-sitemap.xml
Sitemap: http://www.occupyhln.org/category-sitemap.xml
Sitemap: http://www.occupyhln.org/post_tag-sitemap.xml
Sitemap: http://www.occupyhln.org/author-sitemap.xml
```

Specifically, Google is telling me this:

[image]

I did just what it said.  I went to the day with the errors (Oct. 21), and all of the links they said there were errors to are fine.  The only thing I can guess is that my server was down for a short bit -- common with HostGator VPS servers and their 75-80% uptime.  And that's when Google accrued the errors -- and if that's the case, I should fetch as Google, now that it's resolved?

Or is there something wrong with my robots.txt file, which has **permissions set to 644**?
Should the permissions be something else?

Comment: As long as you can access the robots.txt from your browser, it does not have to do anything with file permissions.

Comment: Sure looks to me like they're saying that Googlebot couldn't read robots.txt. If the permissions are okay, then your assumption about down time seems like most reasonable explanation.